# RStudio revert button seems to act like Git reset

Tags: git, rstudio, git-checkout, git-reset, git-revert

I am quite new to RStudio and Git, so I would like to make sure that I understand correctly what I am doing.

The Git documentation says that `git revert` creates a new commit. When I press the RStudio revert button, no new commit is created, it just goes back to the last commit. To me this seems to be a `git reset --hard`. Did I get anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**RStudio** Revert functionality differs from `git reset` functionality.

According to this [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) `git reset --hard` do this

> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the
>   working tree since  are discarded.

So your full project will return to previous commit state

But according to this **RStudio** *Revert Changes* popup  window:
only **selected file** will be changed to previous commit state.

[image]

And this can be done with git combination of

- `git reset file` (Unstage a file)
- `git checkout file` (Discard changes in the working directory)

See more about resetting, checking and reverting [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting/summary)